# how to add an object records to Map

Tags: map, collection

I have an custom object called MapTesting and this object contains 10 records. I created one apex class. In apex class i created one Map like following.

```
public class Example {

    public Map<string, MapTesting__c> mp {set;get;}
     public void method(String mail){


      }
}
```

Now i wanna add MapTesting records to Map.
Can any one give solution?

Thanking You
KS Kumar

Comment: you want to query `MapTesting__c` records and want to add into map? also why map key is string are you planning to assign something else other than Id?

Comment: I do not want to use query and i have to use string as key. 
can we add the records with querying the records?

Comment: check Vigneshwaran G's answer that should work for you. OR You want to store record Id in map key then use `map<Id,MapTesting__c>`.. One more question you want to query the record when VF page loads or when your `method` called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
public class Example {

 public Map<string, MapTesting__c> mp {set;get;}
 public void method(String mail){
     mp = new Map<string, MapTesting__c>();
     //1st way
     for(MapTesting__c mt : [SELECT FieldName FROM MapTesting__c Where Condition]){
          mp.put(Id, mt);   
    }
    //2nd way 
    mp = new Map<string, MapTesting__c>([SELECT FieldName FROM MapTesting__c Where Condition]);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the MapTesting__c records and assign it to Map directly. Change the definition of map to use Id as key for better results and your method should be

```
public void method(String mail){
    mp = new Map<Id,MapTesting__c>([select id from MapTesting__c]);
}
```

[Initialising Maps from Queries](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/initialising-maps-from-queries) for your reference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query the records into MAP.

**Following is the code:**

```
public Map<Id,MapTesting__c> mp = new Map<Id,MapTesting__c>([Select Id From MapTesting__c ]);
```

If you have a Email as a key and want to associate 10 records with one key, please declare the following map:

```
public Map<string,List<MapTesting__c>> mp = new Map<string,List<MapTesting__c>>();
for(MapTesting__c mp : [Select Id From MapTesting__c]) {
    if( mp.containsKey(email)){
        mp.get(email).add(mp);
    }
    else
        mp.put(email,new List<MapTesting__c>{mp});
}
```